# Function on columns inside dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame

```
Attributes Adj Close                                        
Symbols          OMC       PUB       WPP     ^IXIC      ^DJI
Date                                                        
2015-06-30       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2015-07-01  0.005900  0.001178  0.012686  0.005264  0.007855
2015-07-02 -0.001825 -0.004116  0.001648  0.004484  0.006289
2015-07-06 -0.003267 -0.032502 -0.010842  0.001036  0.003665
2015-07-07  0.015070 -0.037371 -0.017480  0.002142  0.008943
```

I want to iterate through the columns and find the date in which the value in 'PUB' > than the value in '^IXIC'

I was reading through some of the things other people have been posting online, I was thinking about making another column and use np.where to populate it but was wondering if there was any way to get the data without going through that entire process

(Something like a for loop with an if function that goes through the dataframe and returns the date when the condition is met)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need for loop here

```
dates = df.index[df['PUB'] > df['^IXIC']]
```